# What is the difference between running a command as sudo and running a script as sudo?

Tags: shell-script

Why does running the command as `sudo` echo the value of the variable, however, running the same command in a script as `sudo` not echo it?

```
➜ echo "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"
/Users/cc/.config

➜ sudo echo "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"
/Users/cc/.config

➜ cat sample.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"


➜ ./sample.sh
/Users/cc/.config

➜ sudo ./sample.sh


➜
```

P.S. Tried it on linux as well with similar results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sudo echo "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"`, your shell expands the variable before running `sudo`, and `sudo` sees `echo /Users/cc/.config` which it duly runs.

In `sudo ./sample.sh`, `sudo` starts a shell to run the script, and that shell does the expansion. Now, depending on settings, `sudo` might clean up the environment variables, to protect the privileged command from picking up instructions from them.

See the `env_reset`, `env_check`, `env_delete` and `env_keep` settings, and the `-E` option to `sudo`.

You'd get the same effect even without `sudo` if the variable isn't exported in the original shell, e.g.

```
foo=bar
echo $foo
sh -c 'echo $foo'
```